# Laravel elixir npm error Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir/ingredients/commands/Utilities'

Tags: laravel, npm, gulp, utilities

I've came across this problem when I wanted to install a project from a couple of months ago onto my home-computer, i've installed my packages correctly, but when i try to run gulp, i constantly get this error:

Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir/ingredients/commands/Utilities'

I've been debugging for about 5 hours now and i'm close to desperation :p , the solutions they offer online don't even seem appliable, they tell me to change a directory in the index.js of the laravel-elixir module, but the rules that need changing don't even exist in that file :p ,

Any help would mean the world to me!

Comment: Try this: `rm -rf node_modules/`, `npm install`, `gulp`.

Comment: @Geoffrey Orpheuz : did you happen to solve the issue ?

Comment: @Hkan - your suggestion solved my hours of googling. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @Hkan proposed in the comments section:

Running the following commands will remove and reinstall all modules:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm install 
$ gulp
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install && gulp
```

Comment: can you be more precise, what did not work? In my set up it went through smoothly